# Difference between eval("input()") and eval(input()) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I am trying the following function:

```
x = eval(input())
```

Giving input as 123 and type of x is also `int`, it works fine:

```
In [22]: x=eval(input("enter:"))
enter:123
In [24]: print(type(x))
<class 'int'>
```

But while giving input as abcd, it throws the error:

```
In [26]: x=eval(input("enter:"))
enter:abcd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-fb0be0584c85> in <module>()
----> 1 x=eval(input("enter:"))

<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'abcd' is not defined
```

Also when I changed the code to:

```
x=eval('input()')
```

It works fine:

```
In [27]: x=eval('input("enter:")')
enter:abcd

In [28]: print(x)
abcd
```

But when given input as 123, type of x is `str` instead of `int`:

```
In [30]: x=eval('input("enter:")')
enter:123

In [31]: print(type(x))
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`eval` evaluates a piece of code. `input` gets a string from user input. Therefore:

- `eval(input())` evaluates whatever the user enters. If the user enters `123`, the result will be a number, if they enter `"foo"` it will be a string, if they enter `?wrfs`, it will raise an error.
- `eval("input()")` evaluates the string `"input()"`, which causes Python to execute the `input` function. This asks the user for a string (and nothing else), which is while `123` will be the string `"123"`, `?wrfs` will be the string `"?wrfs"`, and `"foo"` will be the string `'"foo"'` (!).

A third version that might make the difference apparent: `eval(eval("input()"))` is exactly identical to `eval(input())`.

Comment: Thanks L3viathan for the answer, But I still have a confusion.
Why doesnt python takes care of abcd like it does for 123. I mean abcd should be automatically converted to string. Why do we have to explicitely give like "abcd" and not just abcd like in the case of normal `input()`.

Comment: Because `abcd` is not a defined name. When you use `abcd` in your python code, it will be for a variable, or function, etc. To make it a string, you need to surround it with double quotes. What's valid in Python code, is also valid in `eval()`. Why should Python automatically convert `abcd` to a string? Why would you use `eval()` if you want a string?

Comment: Is there a way to receive an input from user of any type let it be int, string ,list or dictionary?
I got that from now that `eval(input())` will work fine for this case provided input is given in quotes. Is there way this can be handled without providing string in quotes and cover scenarios of other object types as well?

Comment: @NikhilChhabria How would you then input the string "123"? At that moment it's pure guesswork. Sure, you could do some heuristics, but I don't think that's smart.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focus on the difference between `eval(“input()”)` and `eval(input())` let's focus on their primary similarity:  *you shouldn't do either of them!*

I don't know where the `eval(input())` idiom comes from in Python 3, possibly a misunderstanding porting `input()` by Python 2 users who didn't learn to use `raw_input()` instead, but avoid it!

The right answer in this situation is, if you want a `str`, do:

```
x = input()
```

if you want an `int`, do:

```
x = int(input())
```

But stop using `eval()` as you're opening up your program for all sorts of abuse by a potential user:

```
>>> x = eval(input('enter: '))
enter: __import__("os").system("rm *")
>>>
```

Don't try this at home!  Or work!

If you want to input constant Python data structures, you can try `literal_eval()` from the ast module:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> my_dict = literal_eval(input('enter dict: '))
enter dict: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> my_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> type(my_dict)
<class 'dict'>
>>>
```

But still be cautious!