# Name is not defined when using eval()

Tags: python, eval

I am currently doing miniscript that is sending documents to a specific path based on a code I enter.

The code is basic, but I get an error which I really don't understand.

When I run the following code:

```
en = "English"
source = eval(input("Source language?\n"))
print (source)
```

If I hit `'en'` I get English without any errors.

But if I run the same without input:

```
en = "English"
eval(en)
```

I get `"name 'English' is not defined"`.

Basically, I want to use some of `eval()` functions in my code without the `input()` function. Where I am wrong?

Comment: It is not the same. It would be the same if you did `eval("en")`. Doing `eval(en)` is equivalent of doing `eval("English")` which fails because Python doesn't know how to evaluate that...

Comment: I don’t understand exactly what you trying to do, but in the latter case if you replace eval with print, it should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between eval("input()") and eval(input()) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55144515/6045800)

Comment: Or [What does Python's eval() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9383740/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

Usually there is never any need to use `eval` in `Python`:

```
languages = {'fr': 'french', 'gr': 'greek', 'en': 'english'}
source = languages.get(input("Source language?\n"), 'Undefined language!')
print(source)
```

Out:

```
Source language?
gr
greek
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval` expects a string as its argument.  By passing it `en`, you're giving it the string `"english"`.  Instead, you probably want

```
eval("en")
```

However, using `eval` is generally bad practice.  I'd look into alternative ways of doing what you're after.